# In Rolemaster Unified, can you use the Similar Skill rules on skills like Grace and Spell Trickery

Tags: skills, rolemaster, rolemaster-unified

In Rolemaster Unified spells come in lists (eg Fire Law) that you buy higher levels spells from, using skill points. In addition, there is also a category of skills called "Magical Expertise" skills.  That category has skills that allow you to adjust the penalties for casting a spell in an unorthodox manner. Like casting a spell without gestures, or casting a spell above your character's level.

When you purchase these Magical Expertise skills some of them are to be bought for a specific spell list.  The skill can be developed for multiple lists, but each list developed in such a way costs as if it were a different skill. For example, you might purchase ranks in the skill Grace with a specialization in Fire Law: "Grace - Fire Law 5 ranks".  This will directly decrease the penalty incurred for "overcasting" a spell on the Fire Law list only.  Then you could also spend more points to buy Grace for a separate spell list eg "Grace - Spirit Mastery; 5 ranks".

*See Section 3.14 Rolemaster Unified Core Law (pg 101).*

There is also a Similar Skill rule which allows you to use a skill in a manner that it was not initially intended so long as the GM approves it.  Using the skill in this way reduces it effectiveness at the expense of flexibility.

*See the Similar Skills heading in Section 3 Rolemaster Unified Core Law (pg 84).*

Typically you use similar skills for skills that are making a skill check. (eg Use your Crossbow skill at a penalty to fire a Bow, or use your Acting skill when you have to make a public speech) But these skills have no skill check associated with them - instead they are used to offset a penalty.

**So, can you use the Similar Skills rules on skills like Grace or Spell Trickery that are reducing a penalty and not used to make a skill check directly?**